# WebView does not load some complex html5 webs (like games) on all devices... only in some of them

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

i noticed that some complex html5 websites does not load properly on all devices. For example, Samsung Galaxy S5 does not load properly those complex html5 websites. Instead of it the webview shows a black empty website.

This haves any explanation?

this is my webview:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom( allowZooming );   
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(allowZooming);     
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

This is the game that does not work: http://tinyurl.com/krahudh

Comment: are those complex html5 websites correctly rendered in the S5 native browser?

Comment: yes, they are correctly rendered

Comment: maybe something to do with https ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697946/webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blank-page

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry this response comes so late.  Hopefully you have been able to find a solution to this issue already, but in case you are still working on it:  I had a very similar problem and this person's, [Android webview does not load the page but app load from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153657/android-webview-does-not-load-the-page-but-app-load-from-browser/22642955#22642955), answer helped in my situation anyways.

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Although, I altered it slightly in the code I used to best suit the purposes for which I was using it.  The code I used was

```
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

.  I hope this helps.